# ¿Cuál es una traducción apropiada para "Thinking out of the box"?

Tags: traducción, modismos, solicitud-de-término

El otro día, resolviendo con los compañeros de trabajo una serie de problemas, me vino a la cabeza la expresión `Thinking out of the box` (o [`thinking outside the box`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinking_outside_the_box)). Esta expresión viene a significar que debes pensar de una manera distinta, no convencional para resolver un problema.

Me di cuenta de que esta es una de esas expresiones que estoy tan acostumbrado a oirlas en inglés que no sé (si es que lo hay) un equivalente en español. No sé si se fuerza una traducción directa tipo

> Pensar "fuera de la caja"

o si se usan otros modismos tipo

> Pensar de "manera **rompedora**" (o *novedosa*, *creativa*,...)

Siempre se pueden buscar otras palabras para definirlo, como "nueva perspectiva", "pensamiento creativo", "pensamiento innovador", etc. pero que no recogen del todo bien el significado de la expresión (podríamos usar esos términos para cosas que no fuesen necesariamente "out of the box").

Me pregunto si la expresión en sí tiene equivalente en español, ya sea bien otro modismo o la traducción directa. Un paseo por google y ciertos sitios [no ha arrojado demasiada luz](http://www.linguee.es/ingles-espanol/traduccion/think+out+of+the+box.html) sobre el tema. Sé que existen términos como `pensamiento lateral`, pero este es por supuesto la traducción directa de `lateral thinking` (y supongo que es lo mismo para `pensamiento expansivo`).

¿Existe un equivalente (traducción literal o modismo) para `thinking out of the box`?

Comment: Hubo un debate interesante sobre esta frase en Wordreference: [think outside the box (think out the box / think outside of the box)](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/think-outside-the-box-think-out-the-box-think-outside-of-the-box.156300/). Ahí veo cosas que nunca oí (la traducción literal, por ejemplo) pero sí otras como "no seas cuadrado" (si bien tiene una connotación mala no existente en el original), "innova", "sal de la rutina" (tal vez demasiado genérica), "piensa creativamente" (¡me gusta!), etc. Supongo que en distintos países se verán con buenos ojos diferentes opciones.

Comment: También existe *fuera del cajón* al lado de *fuera de la caja* y *pensamiento lateral*, aunque [no se usa tanto](https://goo.gl/qHty41).

Comment: ¨pensar fuera del molde¨ es otra opción.

Comment: @JoseMaria, sí, esa expresión podría ser una buena traducción para "fuera de la caja"

Comment: El presunto origen de la frase en inglés se puede ver aquí.  https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pensar_fuera_de_la_caja Lo interesante es que en el rombecabezas no hay una caja, sino que la caja es una restricción mental por parte del que intenta solucionarlo.

Comment: También _Out of the box_ tiene significado ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_box_(feature)), [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/out_of_the_box)), y IMHO le transmite a la frase de la pregunta la idea de "lo estándar", "lo producido en serie".

Answer (score 7):

En mi caso yo usaría:

> Pensar más allá

Por ejemplo:

> ¡Hay que **pensar más allá** del problema que tenemos de frente!

Comment: Yo pondría en realidad *pensar diferente*, conlleva más formas de bifurcar el significado.

Comment: "Ver más allá" es más utilizado que "Pensar".

Answer (score 7):

Durante mi etapa de estudiante de ingeniería en España teníamos muchas asignaturas que exigían que olvidásemos todo lo aprendido y pensásemos sin estar condicionados por nuestro conocimiento previo, y de esta manera poder dar soluciones ingeniosas a los problemas. Este hecho siempre lo he visto referenciado como `abrir la mente`. Es más, en muchos acertijos para animar a la gente, se le suele decir `Venga, abre la mente`

Así que creo que una manera apropiada de definir `Thinking out of the box` sería `Abre la mente`

---

Answer (score 4):

Encuentro las otras respuestas útiles pero intentaré aportar algo más.

En español existe **trillado** y **camino trillado**:

> #### [trillado, da](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aeV4xFa)
>
> **1.** [adj.](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26447/12991) Común y sabido.

> #### [c̲a̲m̲i̲n̲o̲ trillado, o c̲a̲m̲i̲n̲o̲ trivial](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6xxQ4ub#BkT1sQR)
>
> **2.** [m.](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26447/12991) Modo común o regular de obrar o discurrir.

Podemos construir expresiones como **salirse de lo trillado** o **reflexionar por caminos poco trillados**.

Atendiendo al origen de la expresión (el hecho de no inventarse limitaciones que no existen), creo que se puede añadir **pensar sin encajonarse<sup>2</sup>** (obsérvese que el verbo se usa más como pronominal). Yo añadiría que se usa principalmente en sentido figurado, como en nuestro caso.

> #### [encajonar](http://dle.rae.es/?w=encajonar)
>
> **2.** [tr.](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26447/12991) Meter en un sitio angosto. [U. m. c. prnl.](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26447/12991)

Decirle a una persona "think out of the box" en inglés es como decirle en español "piensa sin encajonarte".

Esto en cuanto al uso verbal. La expresión **pensamiento sin encajonamiento** es algo cacofónica para traducir el sustantivo. Al menos, si nos empeñamos en usar "pensar" o "pensamiento". Sin embargo, el verbo *to think* aquí significa más **idear**, puesto que siempre se usa en situaciones en las que, de lo que se trata, concretamente, es de inventar, resolver, crear… Traduciendo más libremente con el objetivo de reproducir con más fidelidad la idea que se intenta transmitir, el adjetivo que se me ocurre es **audaz**. Se trata de *idear* de forma *audaz* o llegar a una *idea audaz*. Y aquí voy a ser audaz yo también y voy a proponer algún que otro neologismo:

1. **Audacidear** y **audacidea**. El arte de tener ideas audaces sería *el audaz idear* (en línea con [*el gay saber*](http://universojus.com/definicion/gaya-ciencia-o-gay-saber)). En inglés no sé cómo se diría de forma sencilla (¿*out-of-the-box-thinking*?).
2. Si a alguien le resultan estas palabras muy largas o complicadas de pronunciar tal vez se podría acortar a **audear** y **audea** (existe el verbo latino *audĕo, -es, -ēre, ausus sum*, de la misma raíz que "audaz" y "osar").
3. **Atrevidear** y **atrevidea**.

Por ahora, eso se me ocurre.

---

Viendo la respuesta de **Richard** y los comentarios de **jalazbe** y **Brian H.**, tengo que decir que sí que existe el "ser cuadriculado":

> #### [cuadriculado, da](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BPcvXtY)
>
> **1.** [adj.](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26447/12991) Rígido, poco flexible, cerrado a nuevas ideas o costumbres. *Es una persona de mente cuadriculada.*

Así que, aunque supongo que en México se entiende lo de "no ser cuadrado", "no ser cuadriculado" debería entenderlo cualquier [hispanófono](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/332775533853151232?lang=es).

Answer (score 3):

Yo diría, pensar de otra manera saliéndose del molde.

Answer (score 3):

Hay algunas respuestas interesantes. Sin embargo, pienso que no sería el modo de utilizarlas cotidianamente.

> Ver más allá del problema.
>
> Ser de mente abierta o Tener la mente abierta.

La frase que más me hace pensar en "thinking outside the box" es

> Romper el molde.

Un uso sería

> "Este producto es revolucionario. La empresa **rompió el molde** con el nuevo diseño..."

Comment: Para mi "romper el molde" tiene más connotación de "irrepetible" y "novedoso". "Thinking out of the box" se refiere más a otra forma de abordar el problema o de idear una solución. En definitiva, creo que es posible "romper el molde" y destacar con un producto o solución sin que esta refleje necesariamente una muestra de "pensamiento lateral" o "thinking out of the box".

Answer (score 2):

Pienso que “pensar más allá de lo ordinario” o “fuera de lo ordinario/común” “fuera de límites “ “fuera de base” podrían ser algunas de las opciones que transmitirían el mismo concepto.
Me inclino más a “fuera de lo común”

Answer (score 2):

Primero, hay que definir el formato deseado: no conviene una frase negativa.

Luego, hay que imaginar una situación donde se usaría comúnmente esta frase.  Entonces, un ejemplo:

> Varias personas están en una reunión, buscando la solución de un problema, o tratando de mejorar algun plan de acción.  Entonces alguien, quizás el jefe/la jefa del grupo, exhorta a los compañeros:
>
> "Quiero que **consideren todas las opciones, hasta las más inesperadas**."

Porque el que exhorta quiere que se desechan las premisas normales, para poder pensar con más creatividad, sin inhibiciones.

Otra opción:

> Olviden las normas.

Answer (score 1):

Desde mi punto de vista la expresión anglosajona "Think outside the box" puede reflejarse en castellano mexicano (y no sé si lo entiendan de la misma manera en otros países), como ***no seas cuadrado*** o ***no seas cerrado***, refiriéndose esto a la manera de pensar de a quien se le diga dicha expresión.

Comment: La verdad es que en castellano lo de "no seas cuadrado" es una expresión que no he oído nunca y que no la veo como traducción de la frase "Think out of the box"

Comment: sin embargo si alguien dijera "no seas cerrado" si que lo entendería como "Think out of the box", dado el contexto apropiado obviamente.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Thinking outside the box***

puede traducirse como

> ***Pensando de manera no convencional***

Answer (score 0):

**"Pensamientos fuera de rango"**

*Pensamientos locales*. Pido perdón por la extensión.

Cuando adolescente teníamos un grupo de amigos, algunos de ellos ingenieros y arquitectos de los primeros cursos, a los que les gustaba ponernos distintos tipos de ejercicios que intentaban solventar problemas realmente complicados pero con apariencia de tener una respuesta ridículamente fácil. Sin embargo una vez, después de los primeros minutos, con intentos de entenderlos y abarcarlos de forma conveniente y tradicional, la respuesta no llegaba nunca.

Recuerdo que en algunos de esos "problemas", para dar correcta solución había que ir más allá del rango del papel ó aquello que marcaba límites al propio folio, donde teóricamente deberíamos encontrar y escribir la solución. De esta forma entendimos, de forma práctica, que para solucionar determinadas problemas, podríamos darnos cuenta, que parte del problema podía no hallarse dentro del marco del papel, sino estar más allá. Este más allá, era romper los esquemas tradicionales en la resolución de los problemas, ya que el problema podía estar en el papel, pero su solución no, y esta pudiera hallarse más allá del propio papel. En estos casos, había que trazar líneas ó cualquier otra operación que saliera de folio utilizado para el caso, buscando el punto que daba la clave de la resolución.

A este tipo de ejercicios o problemas, en que se nos decía que había que ir más allá de lo aparente y buscar la solución incluso en cualquier cosa, incluso que pudiera ser ridículo ó contradictorio.

Cuando sabíamos que los ejercicios, iban a ser de esta índole, los llamábamos, en versión corta "**fuera de rango**", pues eran problemas que para su solución iban más allá del papel, "**irse fuera de rango**", era que necesitabas dar con una solución que estuviera fuera de lo habitual, es decir, fuera de los valores o categorías que posees de antemano, fuera del rumbo o conducta que se espera como actuación.

Quizás "**Irse de rango**", "Fuera de rango", sea un término más coloquial, no lo se, pero era el que nosotros utilizábamos en aquellos veranos cuando nos juntábamos para realizar estas actividades, para nosotros entonces tan divertidas, desde entonces personalmente cuando tengo que dar una solución no convencional ó hay que tener más cosas presentes o en cuenta, utilizo la expresión ó el dicho "**Pensamiento/s fuera de rango**", "**Irse de rango**", "**Fuera de rango**". Esta última también puede expresar que estas tan "fuera de rango", que no ves el problema y necesitas volver al papel. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo propongo traducirlo por:

> **Pensar de forma imaginativa, adoptando una nueva perspectiva**.