# Traduccion de Uninterested vs Disinterested en español

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, adjetivos

Hoy me encontré con [una cita](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/88064/how-to-not-appear-uninterested-in-an-interview#comment256269_88064) que decía:

> To quote the great David Mitchell "I think you mean **uninterested**. All good policemen are **disinterested**."

[*Uninterested*](https://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=uninterested) puede traducirse como "desinteresado" o "falto de interés". [*Disinterested*](https://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=disinterested) puede traducirse también como "desinteresado" y *Wordreference* incluso ofrece `indiferente` y `apático`.

En español, *[desinterés](https://dle.rae.es/?id=D6pvO1f)* tiene los dos significados de "carente de interés" y "carente de la búsqueda de provecho propio":

> 1. m. **Falta de interés** por algo.
> 2. m. **Desprendimiento** de todo provecho personal, próximo o remoto.

Parece ser que hay mucha controversia sobre el uso correcto de ambos términos en inglés. Como sugiere [este sitio](https://web.archive.org/web/20180731022854/https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/usage/disinterested-or-uninterested):

> **[D]isinterested** should never be used to mean ‘not interested’ (i.e. it is not a synonym for **uninterested**) but only to mean ‘impartial‘

Si entendemos que la frase original viene a significar:

> Entiendo que quiso decir "carente de atención, ganas o interés". Todos los buenos policías son *altruistas, sin segundas intenciones*.

¿Cuáles serían los términos correctos en español para traducir **uniterested** y **disinterested** en esa frase?

Answer (score 5):

I needed some context for the quote, as it wasn't immediately obvious whether this person Mitchell was talking about an uninterested policeman.  It turns out he was.  As far as I can tell from my googling efforts, Mitchell appeared on some television program I never heard of, called "Would I Lie to You?"  I found a [more complete quote](https://rionaleonhart.dreamwidth.org/292753.html?thread=10587281):

> Brydon [the host, I think] at one point described Mitchell's demeanour as 'like a disinterested policeman'.
>
> Mitchell: Uninterested, surely. All good policemen should be disinterested. (Brydon is confused.) 'Disinterested' means 'impartial'.

So here's how I would translate the (hopefully more accurate and complete) Mitchell quote:

> Creo que más bien Ud. quería decir que no me veo muy interesado, es decir, que no se me nota ninguna curiosidad por el asunto.  Todo buen policía debe mantenerse desinteresado.  "Desinteresado" quiere decir "imparcial."

Here are some examples from other contexts:

> El juez no se veía muy interesado en el caso.  Durante las declaraciones preliminares bostezó varias veces.
>
> Pero la esposa del juez Martínez es prima hermana del acusado.  La prensa va a decir que Martínez no está desinteresado.

Answer (score 4):

I would consider playing with the difference between ser and estar:

> Querrá decir que **estaba** desinteresado. Un buen policía siempre **es** desinteresado.

I've also made "es" bold for clarity's sake, but bear in mind that in actual delivery, it wouldn't be emphasized as much as the "estaba".

This difference between "ser desinteresado" (impartial, altruistic) and "estar desinteresado" (bored, not paying attention) is quite general, and applies in many more contexts than this particular sentence.

Comment: Brillante forma de resolver el problema [_thinking out of the box_](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13680/5481)

Comment: I think I also covered this.

Comment: @Lambie: No you didn't. You did not make any mention whatsoever to the difference between "ser interesado" and "estar interesado". And you're five year late.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the English language *shot itself in the foot* with two words that in one definition are synonyms and in the other are not

According to Merriam-Webster (my go to English dictionary) David Mitchell is in some sense wrong since [Disinterested](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disinterested) has both meanings of **not interested** and also **not selfish, unbiased**

> Definition of disinterested
>
> 1
>   a :  not having the mind or feelings
>   engaged
>   b :  no longer interested
>   husband and wife become disinterested in each other — T. I. Rubin
>
> 2 :  free from selfish motive or interest  :  unbiased
>   a disinterested decision

but [uninterested](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uninterested) only means **not interested**

In Spanish we don't have "uninteresado" and we only have "[desinteresado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=D6rCmSt)" that also has both meanings.

> Fue una propuesta desinteresada (libre de propósitos egoístas)
>   El se muestra desinteresado por el juego (no está interesado en el juego)

All this makes things more confusing since the exact translation for both *uninterested* and *disinterested* would be **desinteresado**

The way to make it clear would be by using the definitions.

> uninterested = not interested = sin interés
>   disinterested = (2)unbiased = imparcial

"I think you mean uninterested. All good policemen are disinterested."
"Creo que quiso decir *sin interés*. Todos los buenos policías deben ser *imparciales*"

Comment: I am not interested in this book is not sin interés. That would be: I have no interest in this book. Este libro es sin interés para mi. To not be interested in something is usually: no interesar mas or desinteresar.

Comment: @Lambie: *"Este libro es sin interés" is just broken Spanish. "To not be intereseted" is not any of the two translations you have suggested. It is "no estar interesado". "No interesar más" would be "doesn't interest me anymore", while "desinteresar" is a made up word. "Desinteresarse", instead, would be "to lose interest"

Comment: @Wences No, it is not broken Spanish. It means the book has no intrinsic value. And what you say, I repeat, is mistaken: "uninterested = not interested = sin interés" That is not accurate. I am not interested in this book. No estoy interesado en este libro. Este libro no me interesa.

Comment: @Lambie: no. "Este libro es sin interés" is broken Spanish. The right way of saying that is "Este libro no tiene/ofrece/reviste (ningún/el menor/nada de) interés". And yes, uninterested does mean "sin interés" but in a different sense than what you seem to have construed it to: to be uninterested is "sin interés" in the sense of "no tengo interés en el caso, soy por lo tanto, una persona sin interés en el caso".

Comment: to be uninterested in something is not sin interés. It's as **you just wrote**: no tener interés en algo.

Answer (score -2):

Collins Dictionary:

**disinterested**

ADJECTIVE

1. (= impartial) desinteresado ⧫ imparcial [disinterested parties: partes desinteresadas]
2. (= uninterested) indiferente [to be uninterested in: ser indiferente a algo]

Spanish translation of 'uninterested'
Word Frequency
**uninterested**

ADJECTIVE
(= indifferent) indiferente ⧫ desinteresado
I am quite uninterested in what he thinks.
Me es igual or indiferente lo que piensa.

to be uninterested in a subject.
no tener interés en un tema
Copyright © by HarperCollins Publishers. All rights reserved.

The point of all this:

In English, you can say I am interested or not interested in something.
That idea in Spanish is: ser indiferente a x OR no me interesa x.

However, to **become uninterested** in something would be:
Se desinteresó del problema. OR: Ya no le interesa el problema.

In English, we normally do not say: He became disinterested in the problem. You can say it but people don't say it usually. However, in Spanish, they do use desinteresar like that.