# Demonyms in Spanish for the planets of the Solar system?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, gentilicio

The Spanish Royal Academy has registered in the DLE demonyms for the imaginary inhabitants of some of the objects in the Solar system (apart from Earth, whose [inhabitants](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Zce8NhA) are not imaginary):

- Moon: [Selenita](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XUVPqh4).
- Venus: [Venusiano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=baAwVRh) or [venusino](http://dle.rae.es/?id=baGlglq) (these two do not include the "imaginary inhabitant" definition, but the "relative to Venus" one).
- Marte: [Marciano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ONTtLFO).
- Júpiter: [Joviano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MY8YrEF).

I can't find other similar demonyms in that dictionary. So are there any other demonyms in Spanish used (in press or literature) or proposed for the rest of the main objects in the Solar system?

Comment: Para Venus también vale "venusino", según la RAE, que era el yo conocía.

Comment: @Alicia añadido, ¡gracias!

Answer (score 6):

Según la RAE, tenemos algunos adjetivos más para los planetas, aunque no figuran como gentilicio, sino sólo como "perteneciente o relativo a":

- **Mercurio**: [Mercurial](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OzTy7ms).
- **Venus**: [Venusino/a](http://dle.rae.es/?id=baEhNGI%7CbaGlglq), además de venusiano.
- **Júpiter**: [Jupiterino/a](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MdXLS2d) además de joviano (palabra que no había oído en la vida, por cierto).
- **Saturno**: [Saturnal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XLeTuKf).

Además de estos gentilicios "oficiales", seguro que en la literatura/cine/series de ciencia-ficción hay un amplio uso de otros más o menos "inventados". La cuestión es si se sigue algún tipo de consenso o no, y si sí, dónde estará recogido dicho consenso.

Algunos ejemplos que se me ocurren:

- **Neptuno**: [neptunianos](http://es.futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Neptunianos), según Futurama.

Comment: Imagino que, por ejemplo, entre "jupiterino" y "joviano" habrá la misma diferencia que entre "terrestre" y "terrícola".

Comment: ¡Amé la referencia a futurama!

Answer (score 4):

There are other demonyms in literature, but their validity is uncertain (as it was proved by the fact that you could not find more in the dictionary).

**Neptuniano** as a demonym of **Neptuno** is, apart from the reference in [Alicia's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22969/5481), present in wiktionary

> [Neptuniano](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/neptuniano): Originario, relativo a, o propio de el planeta Neptuno.

Interestingly, the DRAE gives this word a different meaning, that has little to do

> [Neptuniano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QPeWzKo) (neptúnico)
>
> Dicho de un terreno o de una roca: De formación sedimentaria.

Similarly wiktionary's "**[plutoniano<sup>1</sup>](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/plutoniano)**/-a: del planeta Plutón" has a complete different meaning in DRAE

> **[Plutoniano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TS6IkgM)** (plutónico)
>
> Perteneciente o relativo al plutonismo (vulcanismo).
>
> > [vulcanismo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c57CPfi)
> >
> > Conjunto de fenómenos relacionados con los volcanes y su actividad.
> >
> > Teoría que atribuye la formación del globo a la acción del fuego interior.

And "**[uránico/-a](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/ur%C3%A1nico)** (uranita): del planeta Urano" has another problem. *Uránico* is not present in the DRAE, and neither *uranita*, which is a [uranium-rich radioactive mineral](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uraninita) (thus the name).

Wiktionary includes in [its entry for_gentilicios_](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ndice:Personas/Gentilicios/ES/Orden_alfab%C3%A9tico) "solar" as

> solar: 1. del Sol - 2. **del Sistema Solar**

which again is technically not true by the DRAE (DRAE says for [solar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YFwH0Z4%7CYFwb5VI%7CYFx3PfA%7CYFxNsi9) that is relative to the Sun as a star, not to the Solar system).

Wikipedia also has [its own list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectivals_and_demonyms_of_astronomical_bodies#Planets), but the article is unfortunately not available in Spanish. This list includes

- Earth: Earthling, Terran, Terrestrial, Tellurian, Earthian
- Jupiter: Jovian
- Mars: Martian
- Mercury: Mercurian, Hermean
- Neptune: Neptunian
- Saturn: Saturnian
- Uranus: Uranian
- Venus: Venusian, Cytherean, Vesuvian

but if you were to translate or adapt Neptunian as *neptuniano* and Uranian as uranio you'd run into the problems described above: the dictionary does not include these terms with such meanings.

---

<sup>1. While the dwarf planet  Pluto can be out of the list according to the  "[Great Planet Debate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto#IAU_classification)" I decided to include it in this answer to illustrate the difference between literature about the demonyms and their validity according to DRAE.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Podemos agregar éste:

> **[europeo, a](http://dle.rae.es/?id=H7DymBX)**
>
> Del lat. *Europaeus*.
>
> 1. adj. Natural de Europa. U. t. c. s.

ya que la definición de la RAE no especifica a cuál Europa nos referimos.

> **[Europa (satélite)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europa_(sat%C3%A9lite))**
>
> Europa es el sexto satélite natural de Júpiter en orden creciente de
>   distancia y el más pequeño de los cuatro satélites galileanos.

Comment: Great answer. A brilliant way of [thinking outside the box](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13680/5481)