# ¿Existe una traducción para "Out of the box" en el sentido de algo que está listo para usar?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

Una expresión que he visto frecuentemente en inglés, principalmente en temas relacionados con tecnologías, es el de *Out of the box*. Aunque pareciera relacionada con la expresión "[Thinking out of the box](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/13680/cu%C3%A1l-es-una-traducci%C3%B3n-apropiada-para-thinking-out-of-the-box)" ,
en este caso *Out of the box* es algo que está listo para ser usado. Ej:

> Spring boot is a utility for setting up applications quickly, offering an **out of the box** configuration in order to build Spring powered applications.
> ([Pregunta en Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32923000/5440828)).

Wikipedia en inglés tiene una entrada para el término:

> [**Out of the box (feature)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_box_(feature))
>
> An out-of-the-box feature or functionality (also called OOTB or off the shelf), particularly in software, is a feature or functionality of a product that works immediately after or even without any special installation without any configuration or modification. It also means that it is available for all users by default, and are not required to pay additionally to use those features, or needs to be configured.

Como lo veo, este término sería una metáfora en inglés. Algo "fuera de la caja" da la idea de un producto que ya desempacado y está listo para ser usado. ¿Tenemos en español también una metáfora para este término? ¿O es la traducción simplemente "listo para usar"?

Comment: En el caso de "spring boot" creo que lo podrías traducir con "que viene ya configurado"

Answer (score 9):

A mí me parece que ***listo para usar*** es la forma en la que más gente te entendería sin mayor explicación. [WordReference la recomienda](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=out%20of%20the%20box) y no se me ocurre ninguna otra.

Comment: OOTB no significa listo para usar, aun es requerido cierto tipo de despliegue para usarse, a lo que se refieren con "out of the box" es que tienes que sacarlo de la caja,  OOTB significa que ya esta construido, pero no instalado. el "ready to use/to be used" tambien puede ser encontrado y literalmente significa que ya puedes usarlo.

Comment: @Mike fíjate que en la pregunta se incide especialmente en software y la descripción de la Wikipedia habla de que puede referirse a cuando funciona inmediatamente. Por tanto, creo que _listo para usar_ sí cubre este concepto.

Comment: te puedo decir que por experiencia propia hay una gran brecha entre esa definición y lo que en realidad sucede, pero la principal es que las funciones OOTB se caracterizan por ser "opcionales", por lo común definimos "listo para usar" a lo que ya se encuentra instalado en la paqueteria inicial, pero los OOTB son aquellos que están incluidos pero el usuario necesita agregar personalmente, esto para evitar tener una sobrecarga de 1,000 servicios activos cuando el usuario solo necesita 5.

Comment: @Mike pero en tal caso el paquete opcional está listo para usar, solamente debes ir a la aplicación general y activarlo. Es decir, en cuanto a la aplicación específica que es OOTB, esta sí que no requiere ninguna modificación. Yo en el mundo del software lo he visto muchas veces mencionado como _plug and play_.

Comment: Tambien hay diferencias.... 
El plug and play y fuera de que plug and play es hardware y OOTB es software, la principal diferencia es que no se usa en especifico para funcionalidad "adicional".
todos los OOTB son "features" adicionales.

Comment: @Mike cierto, tienes razón.

Comment: a lo que voy es que : listo para usar podría ser utilizado en lugar OOTB, pero OOTB no podría ser intercambiable por Listo para usar.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: "**directamente de la caja**", "**de la caja**" o "**en la caja**"

Aquí tenemos un caso de advertising y muchos conflictos incluso dentro de la comunidad de desarrolladores.

La verdad es que estas son dos frases muy similares con significados completamente opuestos:

El primero más usado y más evidente es el de "Pensar fuera de la caja"

El otro es "out of the box" que por su similitud a "outside the box" se ha querido cambiar a "out from the box", de la cual la traducción más fiable sería "directamente de la caja". Esto se utiliza para englobar paqueterías, productos, funciones o servicios de software **opcionales/adicionales** que puedes encontrar directamente dentro del producto sin tener que fabricar nada nuevo.

**ejemplo:**

Tienes un pintarrón Listo para usar:

Tu pintarron esta instalado y en el marco tienes un plumón negro y un borrador:

Tanto el plumón, el pintarrón y el borrador están "listo para usarse", pero tu quieres utilizar un plumón azul a lo que tu vendedor te dice:

> No te preocupes, puedes encontrar el plumón azul "en la caja"

o

> No te preocupes, puedes traer el plumón azul "directamente de la caja"

podríamos decir

> El plumon azul esta listo para usarse, pero ¿donde esta?

lo que OOTB engloba es que hay que sacarlo de la caja para poder usarlo.

Comment: No me parece que esto aporte nada adicional, encima de lo que el OP explicó. Lo que podrías hacer es poner un prologuito al comienzo, p. ej. *Ofrezco estas ideas a manera de comentario, nomás que no caben muy bien en ese formato.*

Comment: disculpa @aparente001, pero... mi respuesta incluye :"directamente de la caja" como una opción. 

si los puntos negativos son por eso... entonces nuevamente me siento decepcionado por una comunidad que vota antes de terminar de leer

Comment: No hay cuidado, Mike.  ¿Por qué no editas tu respuesta para hacer resaltar esa frase?  Por ejemplo se puede poner un TLDR al comienzo, poner la frase en negritas, etc.

Comment: Fíjate que lo de _thinking outside the box_ lo menciona en la pregunta pero no creo que sea relevante en la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

La frase: "An idea out of the box". Significaría algo no encasillado, fuera de lo común.

La expresión "plug and play" es "listo para ser usado". Entiendo que podría significar "enchufar y tocar/ejecutar"; pero se lo entiende y adopta como tal.

Answer (score -1):

En Cuba se utiliza el modismo "nuevo de paquete" para referirse a algo nuevo, que viene de cuando se recibe un paquete postal (una caja por correo)